# How to get params after pathPrefix in android deep linking?

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

What should i write to get value of suffix after `pathPrefix`. 
For example i have a deep link registered in manifest for `pathPrefix="/bills"`

but i have another scenario where sometimes i can get a id with bills such as **/bills/123** so what should i write to handle that in pathPrefix? is it `pathPrefix="/bills/"`.* or what exactly?

write now i have written

```
<activity android:name=".ui.Bills.BillDetailsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="partner.windseworld.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/bills/"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

for suffix scenario.
Its opening properly , but it shows two same apps to select from.
What should i write in manifest to get suffix or param properly from deep link url? or should i use pathPattern here? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Used pathPattern in both the places , using pathPrefix at one place and pathPattern was a problem. pathPattern="/bills" and pathPattern="/bills/.* for two different activities inside  tag with scheme and host.